# asking for Selenium *find_element_by_class_name

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to get the text from the helpful and unhelpful button but I couldn't succeed:

for example: I want to get "6013" for helpful points and "320" for unhelpful points:

my code is:

```
product_helpful.append(container.find_element_by_class_name('css-0').text)    
product_not_helpful.append(container.find_element_by_class_name('css-0').text)
```

you can check the picture for your reference:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCBrI.png)

Comment: There are more than one element with class "css-0". How do you expect selenium to know which one to refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the title attribute to target the helpful vs unhelpful portion of the code

```
product_helpful.append(container.find_element_by_css_selector('[title="Helpful"] span').text)    
product_not_helpful.append(container.find_element_by_css_selector('[title="Unhelpful"] span').text)
```

Note that for this you must use the `find_element_by_css_selector` method from the WebElement.

Comment: _....Use the title attribute to target the helpful vs unhelpful.._ awesome explanation.

Comment: For sure! I just did